# About $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x+1)/f(x)$

Tags: limits

Consider $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$

Intuitively, it seems to me that this limit should equal to 1 because "infinity" and "infinity+1" is essentially the same thing.

However, I'm not sure if this is completely correct.

Secondly, if it is correct, I have no idea how  to show this using the limit laws I have learned (or even where to begin since I don't know that either limit exists seperately so I can't just seperate them)

Comment: Can you show what this would mean for an example function, say, $f(x) = x^2$?  Please add to your post how this question would apply to this f(x).

Comment: it depends on your $f(x)$ is. If, for example , $f(x)=x$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = 1$

Comment: There is no universal answer. Consider such examples as $x$, $e^x$ and $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: You can experiment your intuition with some simple function as $e^x$. What is the result in this case?

Comment: Were you given a function $f(x)$ to work with, Milk Man?

Comment: You should at least specify explicitly the behaviour of $f$ at infinity (you only suggests it in your first sentence).

Comment: The general case seems to have been answered very well by now. Thank you to those who answered. One specific case I'm still unsure of is when lim as x--> infinity of f(x) =0 (because if I try using the limit laws, I get 0/0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even under the assumption that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ (implicit in your question), we cannot say much.

- The limit can be $1$:
  take $f(x) = x$: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+1}{x} = 1$$
- The limit can be any positive number $a>1$:
  take $f(x) = a^x$: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{a^{x+1}}{a^x} = a$$
- The limit can be $\infty$:
  take $f(x) = e^{e^x}$: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{e^{x+1}}}{e^{e^x}} = \infty$$
- The limit can fail to exist:
  take $f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\text{ if } x\in 2\mathbb{N}\\2x &\text{ if } x\in 2\mathbb{N}+1\\ x &\text{otherwise.}\\\end{cases}$: then$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{f(2n+1)}{f(2n)} = 2,\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{f(n\pi+1)}{f(n\pi)} = 1$$

(to have the same "limit of the ratio fails to exist" behavior for a *continuous* function $f$, one can also consider $f(x) = x(2+\cos x)$: $\liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$, $\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} \simeq 1.73 > 1$, and indeed $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$.)

**Note:** the ratio can have a limit $1\leq \ell\leq +\infty$, or no limit; in the latter case, it can even have a $\liminf$ equal to $0$. However, it cannot have a limit $\ell < 1$, as otherwise the function $f$ must be decreasing for $x$ big enough and then cannot satisfy $\lim_{\infty} f = \infty$.

Comment: Answer left as community wiki, feel free to edit/improve.

Comment: Nice work, @ClementC.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks! By now, I think what's in this answer should cover all the cases for $f$ such that $f\to\infty$; except maybe "limit fails to exist but $f$ is continuous" (the function in the fourth bullet is not continuous).

Comment: I can think of $f(x) = x(2+\cos x)$ for that.

Comment: @ClementC. You can steal my example for $\sin x$ :P

Comment: @gimusi I focused on $f$ such that $f\to\infty$ :) (I believe that's what the OP had in mind, and also I didn't want to have a function taking value $0$ in the denominator). But again, it's Community Wiki (no one gets points, everyone can contribute)

Comment: @ClementC. The OP doesn't make any claim about the fact that $f(x)\to \infty$. His/Her point of counfusion is that $\infty+1\approx\infty \implies f(x+1)\approx f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider as counterexample $f(x)=e^x$ then

$$\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=\frac{e^{x+1}}{e^x}=e$$

or also

$$f(x)=\sin (x)\implies \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=\frac{\sin(x+1)}{\sin x}\to N.E.$$

Thus in general the limit depends upon the particular function considered.

Comment: It depends on the function; why showcase only $f(x) = e^x$?  As stated, the question is about function $f(x),$ in general, and seeking $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$.  You choose to showcase only one function?

Comment: please to not steal others people's arguments so openly... Elaborate on the subject instead and make a fully developped answer.

Comment: since the OP is claiming that th elimit should be always equal to 1

Comment: @zwim how is this stealing? no one holds a patent on the function $e^x$

Comment: @zwim steal? do you mean $e^x$ is copyrighted?

Comment: Now you just stole The integrator's comment, gimusi!  Think for yourself.

Comment: @amWhy That's indeed a counterexample since it is $\neq 1$

Comment: I really didn't stole anything, maybe someone else gave the same example in a comment while I was writing here, it doesn't seem a big idea to me. It is just a trivial counterexample.

Comment: My point, @gimusi (and no I did not downvote), is that yes, with some functions, the limit may be $1$, but not so with others.  I.e., as I said in my comment here: it depends on what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: agreed, no one holds a monopoly on counter examples. Just because people say the same answer doesn't mean its wrong, if the answer is correct its bound to be the same .

Comment: why the downvote? This is a perfect counter-example to the question, that is, it shows that its not true in general that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)/f(x)=1$

Comment: @amWhy you are not wrong , maybe you could also add some more counterexamples in this post. teamwork

Comment: @TheIntegrator  There is now an answer which is much more thorough.

Comment: @amWhy Many times I've seen counterexamples given and accepted as an answer. If the claim is "it seems to me that this limit should equal to 1" a counterexample indeed suffices to disprove the claim. Of course one cannot like this kind of answer and can add his own with more details. But I'm sill convinced that mine is a proper answer to the OP. Thanks anyway for your suggestions.

Comment: The point is is to be helpful to the OP and to future readers.  Your answer only shows that the limit need not be $1$, but could be $e$, or $a$ if $f(x) = a^{x}$.  The other answer is much more thorough and explanatory.  The point of answering is not just to get upvotes or an accepted answer.  It is to be as helpful as one can.  Anything you add at this point (like using $f(x) = \sin x$ will be seen by me as simply an attempt to gain more favor, as anything you add has already been said on this post.

Comment: @amWhy Yes I undestand your point, indeed now I've updated adding another example and explaining that  "in general the limit depends upon the particular function considered".

Comment: @amWhy I've just read now your comment in which you accuse me to have stolen the comment by integrator. Are you joking or you are trying to get me angry? I really hope you are joking!

Comment: Joking... sorry if it didn't come across as a joke.  I know humor can sometimes not translate well across languages.  I should have thought of that when I was joking.  It was joking in reference to the comment about you "stealing" an example, a comment which I do not agree with.

Comment: @amWhy Ah ok, indeed I wasn't sure about that. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @gimusi for completeness you could also include the case $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a random series taking the valus of $1$ or $2$
  with same probability: $r:\,\mathbb{N}^{+}\to\left\{ 1,2\right\}$ 
  where $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}r\left(i\right)=\frac{3}{2}$. The possible quotients $\frac{r\left(i\right)}{r\left(i+1\right)}$
  then take random values in $\left\{ \frac{1}{2},1,2\right\}$ 
  with probabilities $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$
  respectively. There is no limit at all!

If however $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)$
  exists, what can we say about the quotient then?

Consider the series $h:\,\mathbb{N}^{+}\to\mathbb{Q}$
  with $h\left(i\right)=\frac{1}{2}^{i}$. Then $\frac{h\left(i\right)}{h\left(i+1\right)}=2$.

So we have a limit, but it is not $1$...

But there need not be a limit of the quotient even in the case that $f\left(x\right)$
  approaches a limit:

With our random function $r$
  as defined above, define a series $d:\,\mathbb{N}^{+}\to\mathbb{Q}$
  with $d\left(1\right)\,:=\,1$ and $d\left(i+1\right)=\frac{d\left(i\right)}{r\left(i\right)}$. The limit is $\lim_{i\to\infty}d\left(i\right)=0$. But $\frac{d\left(i\right)}{d\left(i+1\right)}=r\left(i\right)$
  takes no limit.

By continuos extension of the above series it is obvious there are similar examples for continuos functions. Use splines to construct examples for differentiable functions.

Bottomline: Without some additional knowledge about the function, it cannot even be guaranteed that the quotient takes any limit, let alone $1$.